# How does Java detect if something is a formal parameter or instance data?

Tags: java, parameters, parameter-passing, instance-variables

I'm attempting to figure out how Java decides (excuse me if this sounds like I'm personifying Java) which variables to treat as instance data and which variables to treat as formal parameters. I'm aware that this confusion can be avoided following proper coding techniques, but I'm just curious as to the logic behind it. In the following example:

```
public Foo{
    int a, b, c;

    //this assigns the formal parameters' values to the instance data's values
    public Foo(int x, int y, int c){
        a = x; //makes sense 
        this.b = y; //makes sense
        c = c; //how?
    }

    //how can you tell which value is being dealt with
    public int getBar(int a, int b, int c){
        if(b < (b - b))
            a += 5;
        else
            a += a;
        b = b;
        b += c;
        return b;
    }
}
```

The constructor, `Foo()`, the formal parameters are all being copied into the instance data. This is clear for the first two assignments, but the third one is where I start to have some questions. How does Java know which "c" to use? The one that stores instance data or the one that represents the formal parameter? In the second function (sorry if it's too extreme an example), how would you know/how would Java decide which variables represented instance data and which represented formal parameters.

Comment: The rule is simple.  If a parameter and a field (what you've called instance data) have the same name, then any use of that name refers to the **parameter**, unless it's preceded by `this.`.

Comment: `c = c` doesn't assign to the instance variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically parameters and local variables simply take precedence over fields. This is called [*shadowing of the variable or name*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1). So `c=c` does nothing in your code; it assigns the value of `c` onto itself.

Comment: Wow. That was a really simple answer. Thanks so much. I'll accept as soon as I am able to (8 minutes left).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sheesh, I must be getting amnesia. Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The this keyword tells Java you want to reference an instance variable. Most of the time, this is optional. The problem is that sometimes there are two variables with the same name. In a constructor,one is a parameter and one is an instance variable. If you don’t say otherwise, Java gives you the one with the most granular scope, which is the parameter.